# Command file 'nagios.cmd#015' does not exist issue if passivecheck is sent to NSCA daemon

Tags: centos, puppet, opsview, nagios

**Introduction**

As /usr/local/nagios/etc/nsca.cfg is replaced by the default config if opsview has been restarted the reference to this file that resides in /etc/init.d/opsview was changed to /usr/local/nagios/etc/nsca_puppet.cfg and the latter is deployed using a Puppet ERB template.

**Aim**

The aim is to send passive checks using nsca to Opsview.

The hypothesis was that executing:

```
echo -e "HOST\tService\t0\tRemote File does not exist" | \
sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/send_nsca -H host -c \
/usr/local/nagios/etc/send_nsca.cfg
```

would update the (passive) check that reside in Opsview.

**Result**

Tailing the /var/log/messages indicates the following:

```
Jan 24 14:27:37 host nsca[X]: 
Handling the connection for <ip>...
Jan 24 14:27:37 host nsca[X]: 
Command file '/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd#015' 
does not exist, attempting to use alternate dump file 
'/dev/null' for output
Jan 24 14:27:37 host nsca[X]: 
SERVICE CHECK -> Host Name: 'HOST', Service Description: 
'Service', Return Code: '0', Output: 'Remote File does 
not exist' client <ip>
Jan 24 14:27:37 host nsca[X]: End of connection for <ip>...
```

**Attempts to solve the issue**

1) Perhaps the nsca command should be issued as the nagios user

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/local/nagios/bin/send_nsca
```

Does not solve the issue

2) does ncsa run?

Yes

```
user@host:~$ ps -ef | grep nsca
nagios   PID     1  0 13:38 ?        00:00:00 
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nsca -c 
/usr/local/nagios/etc/nsca.cfg --single
```

3) does it work to send ncsa commands from localhost

No, does not work either

4) Incorrect permissions nagios.cmd?

Seems to be ok

```
user@host:~$ ls -ltr /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nagios nagios 1321 Jan 23 22:13 config_output.last_okay
srw-rw----. 1 nagios nagcmd    0 Jan 24 13:38 nagios.qh
prw-rw----. 1 nagios nagcmd    0 Jan 24 13:38 nagios.cmd
srw-rw----. 1 nagios nagcmd    0 Jan 24 13:38 opsviewd.cmd
```

5) Does it work to send other checks then the passive ones to Opsview using nsca

The issue occurs for all kind of checks

6) `nagios.cmd#015 does not exist`...? nagios.cmd was configured? Or not?

Yes this is correct

7) related bugs to this version of NSCA?

```
user@host:~$ sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/nsca --version

NSCA - Nagios Service Check Acceptor
Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Ethan Galstad (www.nagios.org)
Version: 2.7.2
Last Modified: 07-03-2007
License: GPL v2
Encryption Routines: AVAILABLE
```

Seems to be ok as no issues were found on the internet.

8) Who is allowed to write to nagios.cmd?

User is not allowed to write:

```
user@host:~$ echo hello >> /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
-bash: /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd: Permission denied
```

while nagios is:

```
user@host:~$ sudo su - nagios
nagios@host:~$ echo hello >> /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
nagios@host:~$
```

*/usr/local/nagios/etc/nsca.cfg*

```
command_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
```

**Questions**

Several questions could be asked but the assumption at the moment is that the checks could not be processed as these are not written to nagios.cmd.

1. Where does the `#015` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606757/rsyslogd-and-characters-012-and-015) a `#015` in the syslog corresponds to a `\r`.

The issue was caused because CRs were added by Puppet ERB templates.

Executing the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script):

```
sudo sed -i 's/\r//' /usr/local/nagios/etc/nsca.cfg
```

and restarting opsview solved the issue.

In order to solve the [CR template erb issue in Puppet](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/14285/pup-927-any-workaround/), use `content => regsubst(template("opsview/nsca.cfg.erb"), '\r', '', 'G'),`.

Answer (score -1):

You don't mention running the [nsca server](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/NSCA--2D-Nagios-Service-Check-Acceptor/details). This is the most important piece.

Send_nsca needs data. Here your test is invalid:

```
1) Perhaps the nsca command should be issued as the nagios user
```

sudo -u nagios /usr/local/nagios/bin/send_nsca

Rather, you need to echo first and pipe the data in to send_nsca. Your nsca daemon on the server side is what needs to run as the nagios/nagcmd user/group.

Consult the following guide for more details on how to setup nsca:

http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/nagios.html

Comment: Already did an echo (see step 8 of the attempts)

Comment: nsca server is mentioned and it runs